# How can we set homescreen background from third party application?

Tags: android

I am creating an application from which I want set the homescreen background in android.For Instance- If I select any wallpaper from my application and exit the application, same wallpaper should be applied to the homescreen. Please help by giving examples.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to use Android's [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). Check out this [example](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/set-an-image-as-wallpaper-in-android/).